# Short story about the human race pooling together resources to reach dying race

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, space

It's a great story I read several years ago, and was written in the form of newspaper articles and short narrative.

The humans receive a transmission from an alien race asking for help, and they put their differences aside and use all the nukes to make a spaceship. The ship gets to the coordinates only to find that the planet isn't there, but a galactic organization appears and says that this was all a test to see if the humans were suitable to enter the galactic affairs.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81748/4918 Short story where humans receive false distress signal, lured into galactic federation

Comment: Re-opening due to our [policy on closing story ID questions as duplicates](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7067/31936). This question was closed as a duplicate of [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81748/31936) before that policy was instituted.

Answer (score 13):

This is *The Helping Hand* (1991<sup>1</sup>) by Norman Spinrad.

A summary (emphasis mine, spelling fixed):

> In “The Helping Hand” by Norman Spinrad, **NASA received a radio signal from a planet orbiting Barnard’s star, proving there might be other life**. Soon they decode the transmissions and release them to the public. Images of **creatures in need of help** appear. The humans **work together** and raise enough money to go on a long **journey to Barnard’s star to save these creatures**. But when they get there, it turns out that **it was an elaborate plan to make the Earth a better place**. To save the Barnards, the humans put their differences aside and it brought out the best in them.
> <sub>[From this site](http://theheplinghandabb.weebly.com/summary.html)</sub>

A quote (emphasis mine, spelling fixed):

> The Earth has sent a starship called the Helping Hand *to save the Barnard's* star. It began with 200 men and women from *all different countries*.
> <sub>Passage via [this site](http://theheplinghandabb.weebly.com/passage.html)</sub>

It was published in *Full Spectrum 3* (1991, English), *Galaxies #39* (2006, French), and *Utopiales 2013* (2013, French)<sup>2</sup>.

---

Found this by looking at [John Rennie's answer to another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/81770/102999).

<sup>1</sup><sub>From [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?65352).</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Called "La main tendue" in French.</sub>

Comment: OP hasn't been seen in years, but have an upvote.